# How to capture raw image from android camera

Tags: android, camera

The takePicture rawCallback returns a null pointer. The getPictureFormat only allows for .jpg. While the jpeg can be improved with getParameters() setJpegQuality(100) setParameters, the image returned is still a jpeg. To get a bitmap image BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray needs to be called, which can take 1/2 second to process.

The application I'm working on needs the most detailed image the camera can produce, which does not necessarily mean pretty. The raw camera chip capture format is bayer.

Answer (score 12):

The android (at least mine) has 2 camera parameters `"rawsave-mode"` and `"rawfname"`, with the default `rawsave-mode=0`. By setting `rawsave-mode=1`, the camera will save the raw camera image file, along with performing the other camera functions as usual.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters=preview.camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("rawsave-mode", "1");
parameters.set("rawfname", "/mnt/sdcard/test.raw");
preview.camera.setParameters(parameters);
preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, jpegCallback);
```

The actual name of the file produced get modified to include the parameters of the raw file being produced. For one of my androids, the name produced is `"test__1604x1206_10_2.raw"` which is a1 `1604x1206` image, `10bit` format 2. and `"test__1284x966_10_3.raw"` which is a 1284x966 image, `10 bit` format 3. The `10 bytes` are stored as `2 byte short int (little endian)`.

```
parameters.set("rawsave-mode", "2");
// setting the rawsave-mode to 2 increased the resolution to 3204x2406
// and output the file test__3204x2406_10_2.raw
```

The image data is roughly `8 bit`, but floats within the `10 bit`, where a brighter image might use higher values and darker lower. This allows the image processing software to create a histogram and capture the useful range of the image. Because light is not a constant, it can also be necessary to adjust one channel differently than another to make the image look color correct. There is a lot of info on the web regarding color theory which can explain this fully, but new users beware, the conversion of `10 bit` to `8` gets deep quickly. If you want a pretty picture, use the android picture capture and not the raw image!

The format represents the bayer pattern of the bits. Bayer is a format where the odd/even value of the row and column indicate which color the pixel represents, where `RGB` has an `8 bit` value for each color channel for each pixel, bayer has only one `10 bit` value for pixel, where one pixel is red, then the next green, red, green, red, green. Then the next row has blue, green, blue, green, blue green. To determine the `RGB` value of a pixel requires interpreting the surrounding pixels.

```
Format 2 has pixel order
//            0 1 2 3 4 5
//          0 G R G R G R
//          1 B G B G B G
//          2 G R G R G R
//          3 B G B G B G
```

format 3 has the pixel order of

```
//            0 1 2 3 4 5
//          0 R G R G R G
//          1 G B G B G B
//          2 R G R G R G
//          3 G B G B G B
```

I'm not sure if this technique will work on other androids or if it will work on future androids. If anyone tries this, please add a comment on success or failure. My phones are direct chinese import unlocked iHTC Android phones which have been rooted.

Comment: please how can you say that these are actually raw images if they are saved as .bmp? Please can you help me understand? Thanks for the post anyway !!!

Comment: Sorry my dyslexia kicking in again, the `.bmp` was incorrect and should have been `.raw`, as in 1parameters.set("rawfname", "/mnt/sdcard/test.raw");`. The image file output is a `bayer` image, not an RGB image, so each pixel only has a single 10 bit value which red OR green OR blue. To make an RGB image, the surrounding pixels must be interpreted.

Comment: Interesting, the bayer image isn't the actual "THE" `raw image`. When playing with pipes, there is actually another raw image created first, which is then made into a bayer, then the first file is deleted. The only way I ever got to see the first image was when the camera hung up while trying to use pipes. Since the CMOS chip of the camera is a bayer array, my assumption was the change in format was made for friendliness of having the data on byte boundaries rather than nibble or bit boundaries.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification! Now I have the hurdle of decoding that picture... Thanks again

Comment: The biggest hurdle is figuring out which bayer format you are working with. The simplest thing I found to point the camera at something red OR something green OR something blue and look at the raw image in a hex editor.  The next hurdle might be to convert the 10 bit to 8 bit, this can be as easy as dividing by 4 or more complicated by making a histogram and pulling out the best 8 bits.  Another choice is bayer tends to be bumpy, so you may want to apply a smoothing in the conversion. If your interested, I've got some ugly code I could post Monday.

Comment: thank you! Anyway for the time being I have no intention of going into the hurdle at all. Thank you again. have a nice day.

Comment: i have this parameter available 
`picture-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p,yuv422i-yuyv,rgb565,raw,jpeg`
but not `rawsave-mode` so is it possible for me to get images in raw format ?

Comment: When "raw" is listed as a "picture-format-values", you should be able to just set the picture format to raw and use the standard callback to receive and save the file. What device are you using? I've not seen a device which allows formats others than jpeg. Inside the callback, you would just open an output stream and `outStream.write(data)` Since the device allows other formats, it might also support a rawcallback in the takepicture and allow a raw image and a jpeg both to be saved.

Answer (score 3):

code for capture raw image:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.util.Log;

public class Camera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private int mMode;
    private boolean mIssdcardExist = false;
    private VideoPreview mVideoPreview; //缺VideoPreview这个类
    private int mPrvW = 640, mPrvH = 480;
    private int mDispW = 640, mDispH = 480;
    private int mPicW = 2560, mPicH = 1920;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Camera.Parameters mCameraParam;
    private int mIsPreviewing = 0;
    private volatile int mIsFocused = 0;
    private volatile int mIsCapture = 0;
    private long mFocusStartTime;
    private long mFocusCallbackTime;
    private long mCaptureStartTime;
    private long mShutterCallbackTime;
    private long mRawPictureCallbackTime;
    private long mJpegPictureCallbackTime;
    private final AutoFocusCallback mAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback();
    private final ShutterCallback mShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback();
    private final RawPictureCallback mRawPictureCallback = new RawPictureCallback();
    private static final String CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/CameraEM/";
    private int mAFEngMode = 0;

    public static final int CAPTURE_ID = Menu.FIRST;

    private String TAG = "EM-Camera";

    private final int DIALOG_PROGRESS = 1000;
    private ProgressDlgHandler mProgressDlgHandler = new ProgressDlgHandler();
    private final int EVENT_FULL_SCAN_START = 100;
    private final int EVENT_FULL_SCAN_COMPLETE = 101;
    private boolean mIsTest = false;
    private boolean mProgressDlgExists = false;

    private boolean mIsRawCapture = false;
    private String mRawCaptureFileName;

    private boolean mIsOnPause = false;
    private int mPos = 0;
    private static final int MSG_AF_MODE1_EVENT = 1001;
    private static final int MSG_AF_MODE3_EVENT = 1003;
    private static final int MSG_AF_MODE4_EVENT = 1004;
    private mAFMode1FirstThread threadFirst;
    private AFMode1Thread mode1Thread;
    private AFMode2Thread mode2Thread;
    private AFMode3Thread mode3Thread;
    private AFMode4Thread mode4Thread;
    private RawCaptureThread mRawCaptureThread;
    private boolean mCanBack = true;

    private Button mButtonPass;
    private Button mButtonFail;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_test);

        Window win = getWindow();
        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_REMOVED))
        {
            mIssdcardExist = false;
        }
        else
        {
            File file = new File(CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME);
            if(!file.isDirectory())
            {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            mIssdcardExist = true;
        }

        mButtonPass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera_test_pass);
        mButtonPass.setOnClickListener(mButtonHandler);

        mButtonFail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera_test_fail);
        mButtonFail.setOnClickListener(mButtonHandler);
    }

        @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume ");
        mVideoPreview = (VideoPreview) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        mVideoPreview.setAspectRatio(mPrvW, mPrvH);
        SurfaceHolder holder = mVideoPreview.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mIsTest = false;
        mIsOnPause = false;
    }

        @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mIsOnPause = true;
        if(null != mode1Thread && true == mode1Thread.isAlive()){
            try{
                mode1Thread.join();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }

        }

        if(null != threadFirst && true == threadFirst.isAlive()){
            try{
                threadFirst.join();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }

        }

        if(null != mode2Thread && true == mode2Thread.isAlive()){
            try{
                mode2Thread.join();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }

        }

        if(null != mode3Thread && true == mode3Thread.isAlive()){
            try{
                mode3Thread.join();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }

        }

        if(null != mode4Thread && true == mode4Thread.isAlive()){
            try{
                mode4Thread.join();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }

        }

        if(null != mRawCaptureThread && true == mRawCaptureThread.isAlive()){
            try{
                mRawCaptureThread.join();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }

        }

        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "super onPause.");
        this.finish();
    }

        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
            if(id == DIALOG_PROGRESS){
                ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                dialog.setMessage("It is in full scan, please wait......");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                return dialog;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private class ProgressDlgHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case EVENT_FULL_SCAN_START:
                    showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
                    mProgressDlgExists = true;
                    break;
                case EVENT_FULL_SCAN_COMPLETE:
                    dismissDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
                    mProgressDlgExists = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        mDispW = w;
        mDispH = h;
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceChanged width is : " + w);
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceChanged height is : " + h);
        startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        openCamera();
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            closeCamera();
            Log.i(TAG, "surfaceCreated closeCamera ");
        }       
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            stopPreview();
        closeCamera();
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed closeCamera ");
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            Log.i(TAG, "Enter openCamera to init the mCamera.");
            if(null == mCamera){
                Log.i(TAG, "init the mCamera is null.");
            }
        }
    }
    private void closeCamera() {
        if(null != mCamera){
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
    private void startPreview() {
        mCameraParam = mCamera.getParameters();
        //GW616 Camera preview problem
        // Set a preview size that is closest to the viewfinder height and has
        // the right aspect ratio.
        Size size = mCameraParam.getPictureSize();
        List<Size> sizes = mCameraParam.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(
                sizes, (double) size.width / size.height);
        if (optimalSize != null) {
            mCameraParam.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
        }
        //end
//      mCameraParam.setPreviewSize(mPrvW, mPrvH);
        mCameraParam.set("fps-mode", 0);    // Frame rate is normal
        mCameraParam.set("cam-mode", 0);    // Cam mode is preview
        mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParam);
        Log.i(TAG, "startPreview width is : " + mPrvW);
        Log.i(TAG, "startPreview height is : " + mPrvH);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mIsPreviewing = 1;
    }
    private void stopPreview() {
        if(null != mCamera){
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
        mIsPreviewing = 0;
    }

    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, double targetRatio) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        // Because of bugs of overlay and layout, we sometimes will try to
        // layout the viewfinder in the portrait orientation and thus get the
        // wrong size of mSurfaceView. When we change the preview size, the
        // new overlay will be created before the old one closed, which causes
        // an exception. For now, just get the screen size

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int targetHeight = Math.min(display.getHeight(), display.getWidth());

        if (targetHeight <= 0) {
            // We don't know the size of SurefaceView, use screen height
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)
                    getSystemService(this.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            targetHeight = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        }

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "No preview size match the aspect ratio");
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        Log.v(TAG, String.format(
                "Optimal preview size is %sx%s",
                optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height));
        return optimalSize;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
                this.CapturePicture();
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH:
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_FOCUS:
                return true;        
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void CapturePicture(){
        if(false == mIssdcardExist)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("sdcard not available");
            builder.setMessage("Please insert sdcard.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK" , null);
            builder.create().show();
            return;
         }

         if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_SHARED))
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("sdcard is busy");
                    builder.setMessage("Sorry, your SD card is busy.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK" , null);
                    builder.create().show();
                    return;
        }

        if(true == mIsTest)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"It is in capturing, can not repeat capture.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(true == mProgressDlgExists)
            {
                showDialog(DIALOG_PROGRESS);
            }
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int TestMode = intent.getIntExtra("TestMode", 0);
        Log.i(TAG, "The value of TestMode is :" + TestMode);
        if(1 == TestMode)//AF Mode
        {
            mMode = intent.getIntExtra("AFMode", 0);
            switch(mMode){
                case 1:
                    captureMode1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    captureMode2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    captureMode3();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    captureMode4();
                    break;
            }
         }
         else if(2 == TestMode)//RawCapture Mode
         {
             RawCapture();
         }
         else//not select mode yet
         {
             Toast.makeText(this,"Please select the test mode first!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
    }

    private void captureMode1()
    {           
        Log.i(TAG, "Enter captureMode1 function.");
        threadFirst = new mAFMode1FirstThread();
        threadFirst.start();
    }

    class mAFMode1FirstThread extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            Log.i(TAG, "mAFMode1FirstThread");
            mIsTest = true;

            mAFEngMode = 0;
            mCameraParam.set("afeng-mode", mAFEngMode);
            mCameraParam.set("focus-mode", "auto");
            mCameraParam.set("focus-meter", "spot");
            mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParam);
            mFocusStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mIsFocused = 0;
            mCamera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);

            mCanBack = false;
            takePicture();
            mAFEngMode = 1;
            mCameraParam.set("afeng-mode", mAFEngMode);
            mCameraParam.set("focus-mode", "manual");
            mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParam);
            mPos = 0;
            mCameraParam.set("afeng-pos", mPos);
            mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParam);
            startPreview();
            mCanBack = true;
            Sleep(2000);

            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_AF_MODE1_EVENT);          

            Log.i(TAG, "mAFMode1FirstThread finish.");
        }
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            switch(msg.what){
                case MSG_AF_MODE1_EVENT:
                    mode1Thread = new AFMode1Thread();
                    mode1Thread.start();
                    break;
                case MSG_AF_MODE3_EVENT:
                    mode3Thread = new AFMode3Thread();
                    mode3Thread.start();
                    break;
                case MSG_AF_MODE4_EVENT:
                    mode4Thread = new AFMode4Thread();
                    mode4Thread.start();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(false == mCanBack){
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    class AFMode1Thread extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            Log.i(TAG, "mAFMode1Thread");
            if(true == mIsOnPause){
                mHandler.removeMessages(MSG_AF_MODE1_EVENT);
                return;
            }
            mCanBack = false;
            takePicture();
            mPos ++;
            mCameraParam.set("afeng-pos", mPos);
            mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParam);            
            startPreview();
            mCanBack = true;
            Sleep(2000);            
            if(false == mIsOnPause && mPos <= 50){
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_AF_MODE1_EVENT);
            }
            if(mPos > 50){
                mIsTest = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void captureMode2()
    {   
        Log.i(TAG, "Enter captureMode2 function.");
        mode2Thread = new AFMode2Thread();
        mode2Thread.start();
    }

    class AFMode2Thread extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            Log.i(TAG, "mAFMode2Thread");

            mIsTest = true; 
            mCanBack = true;
            mAFEngMode = 1;
            mCameraParam.set("afeng-mode", mAFEngMode);
            mCameraParam.set("focus-mode", "fullscan");
            mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParam);
            mIsFocused = 0;
            mCamera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);
            mProgressDlgHandler.sendEmptyMessage(EVENT_FULL_SCAN_START);

            mCanBack = false;
            takePicture();
            startPreview();
            mCanBack = true;
            mIsTest = false;
            Sleep(2000);

        }
    }

    private void captureMode3()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Enter captureMode3 function.");
        mPos = 0;
        mode3Thread = new AFMode3Thread();
        mode3Thread.start();
    }

    class AFMode3Thread extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            Log.i(TAG, "mAFMode3Thread");
            if(true == mIsOnPause){
                mHandler.removeMessages(MSG_AF_MODE3_EVENT);
                return;
            }

            mIsTest = true;

            mAFEngMode = 1;
            mCameraParam.set("afeng-mode", mAFEngMode);
            mCameraParam.set("focus-mode", "fullscan");
            mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParam);
            mIsFocused = 0;
            mCamera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);
            mProgressDlgHandler.sendEmptyMessage(EVENT_FULL_SCAN_START);

            mCanBack = false;
            takePicture();
            mPos ++;
            startPreview();
            mCanBack = true;
            Sleep(2000);

            if(false == mIsOnPause && mPos <= 50){
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_AF_MODE3_EVENT);
            }
            if(mPos > 50){
                mIsTest = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void captureMode4()
    {       
        Log.i(TAG, "Enter captureMode4 function.");
        mPos = 0;
        mode4Thread = new AFMode4Thread();
        mode4Thread.start();
    }

    class AFMode4Thread extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            Log.i(TAG, "mAFMode4Thread");
            if(true == mIsOnPause){
                mHandler.removeMessages(MSG_AF_MODE4_EVENT);
                return;
            }

            mIsTest = true;

            mAFEngMode = 0;
            mCameraParam.set("afeng-mode", mAFEngMode);
            mCameraParam.set("focus-mode", "auto");
            mCameraParam.set("focus-meter", "spot");
            mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParam);
            mIsFocused = 0;
            mCamera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);
            mCanBack = false;
            takePicture();
            mPos ++;
            startPreview();
            mCanBack = true;
            Sleep(2000);

            if(false == mIsOnPause && mPos <= 50){
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_AF_MODE4_EVENT);
            }
            if(mPos > 50){
                mIsTest = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void RawCapture()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Enter RawCapture function.");
        mRawCaptureThread = new RawCaptureThread();
        mRawCaptureThread.start();
    }

    class RawCaptureThread extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            Log.i(TAG, "mAFMode4Thread");
            mCanBack = true;

            mIsTest = true;
            mIsRawCapture = true;

            mCameraParam.set("rawsave-mode", "on");
            long dateTaken = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mRawCaptureFileName = CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME + createName(dateTaken);
            mCameraParam.set("rawfname", mRawCaptureFileName + ".raw");
            mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParam);
            mCamera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);
            mCanBack = false;
            takePicture();
            startPreview();
            mCanBack = true;
            mIsRawCapture = false;
            mIsTest = false;
            Sleep(2000);            

        }
    }

    private final class AutoFocusCallback implements android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback {
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean focused, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
            mFocusCallbackTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mIsFocused = 1;
            if(1 == mAFEngMode)
            {
                mProgressDlgHandler.sendEmptyMessage(EVENT_FULL_SCAN_COMPLETE);
            }
        }
    }
    private final class ShutterCallback implements android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback {
        public void onShutter() {           
            mShutterCallbackTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }  
    private final class RawPictureCallback implements PictureCallback {
      public void onPictureTaken(byte [] rawData, android.hardware.Camera camera) {         
        mRawPictureCallbackTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      }
    }
    private final class JpegPictureCallback implements PictureCallback {
      public void onPictureTaken(byte [] jpegData, android.hardware.Camera camera) {           
         mJpegPictureCallbackTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         if (jpegData != null) {
            storeImage(jpegData);
         }
         mIsCapture = 0;
      }
    }

    private void takePicture() 
    {       
        while (mIsFocused == 0) {
            Sleep(100);
        }

        mIsCapture = 1;
        mCaptureStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, mRawPictureCallback, new JpegPictureCallback());
        while (mIsCapture == 1) {
            Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    private void Sleep(long time) 
    {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void storeImage(byte[] jpegData) {
        long time;
        long dateTaken = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String name = CAMERA_IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME + createName(dateTaken) + ".jpg";

        if(true == mIsRawCapture)
        {
            name = mRawCaptureFileName  + ".jpg";
        }

        File fHandle = new File(name);
        try {
            OutputStream bos = new FileOutputStream(fHandle);
            bos.write(jpegData);
            bos.close();
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            fHandle.delete();
        }
    }
    private static String createName(long dateTaken) {
        return DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd kk.mm.ss", dateTaken).toString();
    }

    OnClickListener mButtonHandler = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("test_results", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPre.edit();

            if (v.getId() == R.id.camera_test_pass) {
                Log.i("CameraTest", "-----mButtonHandler----onClick()----camera_test_pass");
                editor.putBoolean("CameraTest", true);
            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.camera_test_fail) {
                Log.i("CameraTest", "-----mButtonHandler----onClick()----camera_test_fail");
                editor.putBoolean("CameraTest", false);
            }
            editor.commit();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(CameraTest.this, SpeakerTest.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

//Ugly code to convert bayer to rgb

```
//test__1604x1206_10_2b.raw
//test__1284x966_10_3.raw
#include <stdio.h>
    unsigned short int bayerImage[2500][3500]; //times 3 allows for forming an RGB image for debugging
    unsigned char bmpImage[30000000]; //times 3 allows for forming an RGB image for debugging
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include "bayer2rgb.h"
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>

/*****************************************************************************
**
*/

int DumpImage( char* pszFilename, BYTE* pImage, int bmpWidth, int bmpHeight,int bmpBits,int bmpFormat)
{
    FILE     *bayerFile;
    FILE     *rgbFile;
    int x,y;
    unsigned char lowOrder,highOrder;
    unsigned char bmpchar;
    unsigned short bayerVal;

    unsigned char bmpheader[62];
    char  FullFilename[MY_MAX_PATH];
    unsigned int  bmrgbFilesize;
    unsigned int minPixel=100000;
    unsigned int maxPixel=0;
    static unsigned int rgbValues[4][1024];

    /*expecting 10 bit bayer */
    if(bmpBits!=10)
    {
        printf("invalid bit specification\n");
        return(-1);
    }
    if(bmpHeight >= 0)
    {
        bmrgbFilesize = (((bmpWidth*24+31)/32)*4)*bmpHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        bmrgbFilesize = (((bmpWidth*24+31)/32)*4)*(-bmpHeight);
    }

    #ifdef LINUX

      strcpy( FullFilename, pszFilename );

      rgbFile = fopen( FullFilename, "w+b" );

      if( rgbFile )

    #else

      strcpy_s( FullFilename, sizeof(FullFilename), pszFilename );

      errno_t  errno;
      errno = fopen_s( &bayerFile, FullFilename, "r+b" );  
      if(errno == 0)
      {
          printf("size %d", strlen(FullFilename)-4);
        memcpy(&FullFilename[strlen(FullFilename)-4],".bmp",4);
        errno = fopen_s( &rgbFile, FullFilename, "w+b" );  
      }
      if ( errno == 0 )
    #endif
    {

/*    0 1 2 3 4 5     0 1 2 3 4 5     0 1 2 3 4 5 */
/*  0 R G R G R G   0 G R G R G R   0 B G B G B G */
/*  1 G B G B G B   1 B G B G B G   1 G R G R G R */
/*  2 R G R G R G   2 G R G R G R   2 B G B G B G */
/*  3 G B G B G B   3 B G B G B G   3 G R G R G R */



        memset(bmpImage,255,sizeof(bmpImage));
        switch(bmpFormat)
        {
        case 2:
//            0 1 2 3 4 5
//          0 G R G R G R
//          1 B G B G B G
//          2 G R G R G R
//          3 B G B G B G
            for(y=0;y<bmpHeight;y++)
            {
                for(x=0;x<bmpWidth;x++)
                {
                    lowOrder=fgetc(bayerFile);
                    highOrder=fgetc(bayerFile);
                    bayerVal=(highOrder * 0x100);
                    bayerVal+=lowOrder;
                    bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                    if(bayerVal<minPixel)
                    {
                        minPixel=bayerVal;
                    }
                    if(bayerVal>maxPixel)
                    {
                        maxPixel=bayerVal;
                    }
                    if(y%2==0)
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //green
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal/2;
                            //if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 20) bayerImage[y][x]-=20; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            //bayerImage[y][x]*=.65;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[0][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //red
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal/2;
                            //if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 10) bayerImage[y][x]-=10; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            //bayerImage[y][x]*=.85;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[1][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //blue
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal/2;
                            //if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 10) bayerImage[y][x]-=10; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            //bayerImage[y][x]*=.85;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[2][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //green
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal/2;
                            //if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 20) bayerImage[y][x]-=20; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            //bayerImage[y][x]*=.65;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[3][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
            for(y=1;y<bmpHeight-1;y++)
            {
                for(x=1;x<bmpWidth-1;x++)
                {            
                    bmpchar=bayerImage[y][x]/4;
                    if(y%2==0)
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //green pixel bayerImage[y][x]
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x])/2;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y][x]/2)+((bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/8);//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=(bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/2;//red
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //red pixel
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/4;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x]+bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/4;//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=(bayerImage[y][x]);//red
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //blue pixel
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=bayerImage[y][x];//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x]+bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/4;//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=(bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/4;//red
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //green pixel 
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/2;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y][x]/2)+((bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/8);//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x])/2;//red
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("format 3\n");
//            0 1 2 3 4 5
//          0 R G R G R G
//          1 G B G B G B
//          2 R G R G R G
//          3 G B G B G B
            for(y=0;y<bmpHeight;y++)
            {
                for(x=0;x<bmpWidth;x++)
                {
                    lowOrder=fgetc(bayerFile);
                    highOrder=fgetc(bayerFile);
                    bayerVal=(highOrder * 0x100);
                    bayerVal+=lowOrder;
                    bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                    if(bayerVal<minPixel)
                    {
                        minPixel=bayerVal;
                    }
                    if(bayerVal>maxPixel)
                    {
                        maxPixel=bayerVal;
                    }
                    if(y%2==0)
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //red
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 10) bayerImage[y][x]-=10; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            //bayerImage[y][x]*=.85;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[1][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //green
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 20) bayerImage[y][x]-=20; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            bayerImage[y][x]*=.65;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[0][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //green
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 20) bayerImage[y][x]-=20; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            bayerImage[y][x]*=.65;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[3][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //blue
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 10) bayerImage[y][x]-=10; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            //bayerImage[y][x]*=.85;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[2][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
            for(y=1;y<bmpHeight-1;y++)
            {
                for(x=1;x<bmpWidth-1;x++)
                {            
                    bmpchar=bayerImage[y][x]/4;
                    if(y%2==0)
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //red pixel
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/4;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x]+bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/4;//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=bayerImage[y][x];//red 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //green pixel bayerImage[y][x]
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x])/2;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y][x]/2)+((bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/8);//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=(bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/2;//red 
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //green pixel 
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/2;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y][x]/2)+((bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/8);//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x])/2;//red
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //blue pixel
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=bayerImage[y][x];//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x]+bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/4;//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=(bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/4;//red
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 4:
//            0 1 2 3 4 5
//          0 G R G R G R
//          1 B G B G B G
//          2 G R G R G R
//          3 B G B G B G
            for(y=0;y<bmpHeight;y++)
            {
                for(x=0;x<bmpWidth;x++)
                {
                    lowOrder=fgetc(bayerFile);
                    highOrder=fgetc(bayerFile);
                    bayerVal=(highOrder * 0x100);
                    bayerVal+=lowOrder;
                    bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                    if(bayerVal<minPixel)
                    {
                        minPixel=bayerVal;
                    }
                    if(bayerVal>maxPixel)
                    {
                        maxPixel=bayerVal;
                    }
                    if(y%2==0)
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //green
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 20) bayerImage[y][x]-=20; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            bayerImage[y][x]*=.65;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[0][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //red
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 10) bayerImage[y][x]-=10; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            //bayerImage[y][x]*=.85;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[1][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //blue
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 10) bayerImage[y][x]-=10; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            //bayerImage[y][x]*=.85;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[2][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //green
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 20) bayerImage[y][x]-=20; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            bayerImage[y][x]*=.65;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[3][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
            for(y=1;y<bmpHeight-1;y++)
            {
                for(x=1;x<bmpWidth-1;x++)
                {            
                    bmpchar=bayerImage[y][x]/4;
                    if(y%2==0)
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //green pixel bayerImage[y][x]
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y][x]+bayerImage[y][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x])/3;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0];//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0];//red
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //red pixel
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y][x]+bayerImage[y][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/3;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0];//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0];//red
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //blue pixel
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/3;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0];//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0];//red
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //green pixel 
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y][x]+bayerImage[y][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x])/3;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0];//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0];//red
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 5:
//            0 1 2 3 4 5
//          0 G R G R G R
//          1 B G B G B G
//          2 G R G R G R
//          3 B G B G B G
            for(y=0;y<bmpHeight;y++)
            {
                for(x=0;x<bmpWidth;x++)
                {
                    lowOrder=fgetc(bayerFile);
                    highOrder=fgetc(bayerFile);
                    bayerVal=(highOrder * 0x100);
                    bayerVal+=lowOrder;
                    bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                    if(bayerVal<minPixel)
                    {
                        minPixel=bayerVal;
                    }
                    if(bayerVal>maxPixel)
                    {
                        maxPixel=bayerVal;
                    }
                    if(y%2==0)
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //green
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            //if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 20) bayerImage[y][x]-=20; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            bayerImage[y][x]/=256;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[0][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //red
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            //if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 10) bayerImage[y][x]-=10; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            bayerImage[y][x]/=256;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[1][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //blue
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            //if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 10) bayerImage[y][x]-=10; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            bayerImage[y][x]/=256;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[2][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //green
                            bayerImage[y][x]=bayerVal;
                            //if (bayerImage[y][x] >= 20) bayerImage[y][x]-=20; else bayerImage[y][x]=0;
                            bayerImage[y][x]/=256;
                            if(bayerImage[y][x]>255) 
                                bayerImage[y][x]=255;
                            rgbValues[3][bayerVal]++;
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
            for(y=1;y<bmpHeight-1;y++)
            {
                for(x=1;x<bmpWidth-1;x++)
                {            
                    bmpchar=bayerImage[y][x]/4;
                    if(y%2==0)
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //green pixel bayerImage[y][x]
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x])/2;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y][x]/2)+((bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/8);//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=(bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/2;//red
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //red pixel
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/4;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x]+bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/4;//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=(bayerImage[y][x]);//red
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(x%2==0)
                        {
                            //blue pixel
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=bayerImage[y][x];//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x]+bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/4;//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=(bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/4;//red
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //green pixel 
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+0]=(bayerImage[y][x-1]+bayerImage[y][x+1])/2;//blue
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+1]=(bayerImage[y][x]/2)+((bayerImage[y-1][x-1]+bayerImage[y-1][x+1]+bayerImage[y+1][x-1]+bayerImage[y+1][x+1])/8);//green
                            bmpImage[(((y*bmpWidth)+x)*3)+2]=(bayerImage[y-1][x]+bayerImage[y+1][x])/2;//red
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("undefined bit format\n");
            return(-3);
            break;
        }
        bmpheader[0]='\x42';
        bmpheader[1]='\x4d';
        bmpheader[2]='\x38';
        bmpheader[3]='\x00';
        bmpheader[4]='\x90';
        bmpheader[5]='\x00';
        bmpheader[6]='\x00';
        bmpheader[7]='\x00';

        bmpheader[8]='\x00';
        bmpheader[9]='\x00';
        bmpheader[10]='\x36';
        bmpheader[11]='\x00';
        bmpheader[12]='\x00';
        bmpheader[13]='\x00';
        bmpheader[14]='\x28';
        bmpheader[15]='\x00';

        bmpheader[16]='\x00';
        bmpheader[17]='\x00';
        bmpheader[18]='\x00';
        bmpheader[19]='\x08';
        bmpheader[20]='\x00';
        bmpheader[21]='\x00';
        bmpheader[22]='\x00';
        bmpheader[23]='\x06';

        bmpheader[24]='\x00';
        bmpheader[25]='\x00';
        bmpheader[26]='\x01';
        bmpheader[27]='\x00';
        bmpheader[28]='\x18';
        bmpheader[29]='\x00';
        bmpheader[30]='\x00';
        bmpheader[31]='\x00';

        bmpheader[32]='\x00';
        bmpheader[33]='\x00';
        bmpheader[34]='\x00';
        bmpheader[35]='\x00';
        bmpheader[36]='\x00';
        bmpheader[37]='\x00';
        bmpheader[38]='\x5a';
        bmpheader[39]='\x37';

        bmpheader[40]='\x00';
        bmpheader[41]='\x00';
        bmpheader[42]='\x5a';
        bmpheader[43]='\x37';
        bmpheader[44]='\x00';
        bmpheader[45]='\x00';
        bmpheader[46]='\x00';
        bmpheader[47]='\x00';

        bmpheader[48]='\x00';
        bmpheader[49]='\x00';
        bmpheader[50]='\x00';
        bmpheader[51]='\x00';
        bmpheader[52]='\x00';
        bmpheader[53]='\x00';

        memcpy(&bmpheader[2],&bmrgbFilesize,4);
        memcpy(&bmpheader[18],&bmpWidth,4);
        memcpy(&bmpheader[22],&bmpHeight,4);

        fwrite( bmpheader, 1, 54, rgbFile );

        fwrite( pImage, 1, bmrgbFilesize, rgbFile );
        fclose( rgbFile );
        fclose( bayerFile );
        return(1);
    }
    return(-2);

} // end DumpImage()


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{

    if(argc !=2)
    {
        printf("wrong number of arugments\n");
        printf("drag file to decode on top of program icon\n");
        return(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n",argv[0]);
        printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
    }
/*
char *str = "sdfadabcGGGGGGGGG";
char *result = strstr(str, "abc");
int position = result - str;
int substringLength = strlen(str) - position;
*/
    char *widthStr = strstr(argv[1],"__")+2;
    int widthInt=atoi(widthStr);

    char *heightStr = strstr(widthStr,"x")+1;
    int heightInt=atoi(heightStr);

    char *bitsStr = strstr(heightStr,"_")+1;
    int bitsInt=atoi(bitsStr);

    char *formatStr = strstr(bitsStr,"_")+1;
    int formatInt=atoi(formatStr);

    //DumpImage( argv[1], bmpImage, widthInt, heightInt,bitsInt,formatInt);
    DumpImage( argv[1], bmpImage, widthInt, heightInt,bitsInt,2);
    printf("done\n");
    return 1;
}
```