# How to capture RAW images with Android?

Tags: android, image-processing, camera

Sorry this has been asked and answered before here 
[How to capture raw image from android camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777953/how-to-capture-raw-image-from-android-camera/14777954#14777954)
, but I would like to have a different opinion.

Indeed I am not convinced that an image saved as .bmp is actually a raw image.

The above mentioned thread arguments that passing

```
Camera.Parameters parameters=previe.camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("rawsave-mode", "1");
```

Will give 10 bit RAW pictures, but from http://www.luminous-landscape.com/tutorials/understanding-series/u-raw-files.shtml
I read that RAW should be 12 bit.

Additionally form Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format
none of the mentioned RAW formats include .bmp extension.

Please if somebody could clarify or give any contribution that would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not close the question, it is my opinion that the subjects needs to be discussed more in depth. The "possible duplicate" might not contain the definitive answer. Thanks

Comment: In that case, shouldn't you at least present some arguments for _why_ the answer doesn't convince you? What tests have you performed that indicate otherwise, etc?